# Bulletproof Coffee - Is There A Good Replacement For Grass-Fed Butter?

Tags: bulletproof

I tried drinking Bulletproof Coffee with grass-fed butter and Brain Octane Oil, but I really didn't like the buttery, creamy taste.

**Does anyone have any suggestions for a replacement for the grass-fed butter?**

I've seen a few people like to use vanilla bean powder, but I don't know if that has the same effect as grass-fed butter or if it's purely for taste.

Comment: Did you see [this question](http://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/498/what-is-the-science-if-any-behind-bulletproof-coffee)? I'm not sure what good is. Good for staying warm? Any fatty butter should do this. Good for eliminating a bit of caffeine & acidity? Just a bit of milk is enough for it, no need to be butter.

Answer (score 6):

I have seen folks use coconut oil as a substitute for grass fed butter (or organic butter, or Irish butter or many other variations I have heard).  Almost all of the substitutes I have heard are fat sources designed to get fat based calories into the coffee.  The vanilla bean powder you have heard about adds almost no calories, but will certainly add flavor.  It accomplishes a very different goal than what the Bulletproof folks are espousing.

Keep in mind there are any number of things you can add to coffee to make the caffeine more palatable.  There is an entire industry surrounding this.  What you really need to ask is what you are trying to accomplish by adding something and find the best ingredient for your needs.  Low or no calories flavoring agents maybe suited if you are just not into the taste of coffee.  If you are looking for a fat calorie source, experimenting with different oils until you find one that fits your needs and has a flavor you can deal with may be the way to go.

Personally I look for more protein and not as much fat in my diet.  I like the taste of coffee.  A plain cup of cone coffee and a serving of organic Greek yogurt accomplishes what I am trying to do just fine and doesn't require breaking out or cleaning a blender.

Comment: Nice answer, +1... I use coconut oil these days myself

Answer (score 0):

Try **ghee**.

Otherwise called as clarified butter. Basically same as butter but without the milk proteins.

As for texture differences:

> [Ghee] blends into Bulletproof Coffee well and is a decent substitute for butter in most recipes, although it’s **more oily than butter** and may change the consistency of a dish slightly. If you do make BP Coffee with ghee, know that **it won’t foam** the way butter does so you **won’t get that frothy latte top**. Don’t worry – it’s still tasty. ([ref](https://www.bulletproof.com/diet/healthy-eating/ghee-vs-butter-which-is-best/))