# Any heath benefits of having butter coffee?

Tags: espresso, health, flavored-coffee

Since the time I knew about unsalted butter coffee, I included it in my life. Every morning, I make a black coffee and put butter into it. I generated a taste for it and now it is perfect cup for me. Is there any real health benefits of it?

Comment: Does [this question](https://coffee.stackexchange.com/questions/498/what-is-the-science-if-any-behind-bulletproof-coffee) answer your question? See also others tagged [tag:bulletproof], which is one type of butter coffee. Your other question: "What are the other best forms of black coffee?" could be made more specific in a separate question. Welcome to [coffee.se]!

Answer (score 4):

Heath benefits of adding butter in your coffee are:
1) Vitamin K is found in butter,which helps in blood clotting and keeping the bones strong into old age.
2) Contains Conjugated linoleic acid (CLA) which helps in weight loss.Not only burning belly fat,also protects against cancer and encourages muscle growth.
3) Adding butter in your coffee can provide more sustained energy.
4) Found Omega 3 fatty acids, play a role in the prevention and treatment of arthritis, inflammation,and high blood pressure.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for detailed answer. I think I shall keep this habit for my lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

The benefits of the unsalted butter in your coffee really depend on, like most things, the quality of the ingredients. You should always use **grass-fed butter** *(butter made from cows milk that have been grass-fed their whole lives)*, and try to go for organic. Also, perhaps better than grass-fed butter would be ***grass-fed, organic ghee***. Ghee is a "*clarified*" butter, meaning less or none of the casein and lactose, meaning even very dairy-sensitive people can usually eat it. On top of that, ghee has more butyrate, an anti-inflammatory fat that keeps your gut lining and metabolism in good shape.

Grass-fed butter and ghee are almost all fat, and they're the good, saturated fat your body and brain need to stomp out hunger and cravings, banishes brain fog, and help you **lose weight**, build muscle, and increase focus and performance. Having these fats in the morning jump start your brain activity and kick start your metabolism, also putting your body into a state of ketosis, which **helps you burn fat**!

Comment: Thanks Michael for your detailed explanation. Understood the sceicne behind butter coffee. Never tried ghee in coffee but I take it with my food. Ghee is aother food item which is confusing to many people. Saturated fat is good for health indeed.